# How to get fixed quantization table from jpeg images snapped from a same camera

Tags: jpeg

I am trying to extract Quantization Table values in c# from different camera images , the Quantization table values are supposed to same for a particular camera model , but what i found is that the Quantization tables are different for a same camera model . Can any body tell me the process of extracting QTables .

Thanks and Regards
Somu

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have one of the cameras with the variable quantization table.

Comment: Yes with one camera i am getting variable QTable , please let me know how cam i get the same QTab.

Comment: If the camera is generating custom QTables for each image then there is no way to get a fixed table. Why must the tables be identical for your work?

Answer (score 0):

JPEG viewer available from several sources by entering into the search window**JPEG VIEWER ** will lead you  to software that can extract the quantazation table that is embedded in JPEG photos. Plus other data such as compression ratio